# Ag-Grid-React Delete row with button defined in cellRenderer as function : Can't remove the row from the rowData technically - it only works visually

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am doing something simple, display data in ag-grid-react with buttons in the last Column. When I click to delete the row, the row is removed from the grid, but ... technically the rowData remains the same, it doesn't get updated after the applied transaction delete.
Here is my code :

```
export const SimpleAgGridReactWithRemoveRow: React.FC = () => {
 
 const [rowDataF, setRowData] = useState([])
 const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>(null);
 const [frameworkComponents, setFrameworkComponents] = useState({removeRow:clientCellRenderer});
     
 const clientCellRenderer = (params) => {
 
    const onClickRemove = (e) => {
        let rowToDelete = params.node.data
        console.log(e.gridApi)
                console.log(e.gridApi.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.rowData)
                console.log(rowDataF) //=> Empty list :(
        console.log(rowToDelete) //works fine
        e.gridApi.applyTransaction({remove: [rowToDelete]}); //=> works fine
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => onClickRemove(params.node)}> </button>
        </div>)
}

const gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
            {headerName:'Name', field:'name'},
            {headerName:'Age', field:'age', editable:true},
            {headerName:'Remove', cellRenderer: "removeRow", colId: "params"},
        ],
        defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
            animateRows: true,
            wrapText:true
        }
    }

    const onGridReady = (params) => {
        setGridApi(params.api);
        setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
    };

const getDataFromApi = () =>{
//here I set the row data with axios call
}

useEffect(() => { 
getDataFromApi();
}) 


return (
    
<div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: "500px", width: "500px"}}>
    <AgGridReact
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      rowData={rowDataF}
      columnDefs={gridOptions.columnDefs}
      defaultColDef={gridOptions.defaultColDef}
      ref={gridRefCurrPairsClient}
      pagination={true}
      paginationPageSize={10}
      frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
      >
    </AgGridReact>
</div>
)
```

This is how it looks :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNIcm.png)

On delete a row it works excellent (e.gridApi.applyTransaction({remove: [rowToDelete]}) does the thing) but how I can update the rowDataF technically ?

I tried many options but I didn't succeed to update the state of the **rowDataF** ....

In my function onClickRemove(), the **e** is RowNode object, and I can access to the rowData content as per: e.gridApi.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.rowData.

I think that between the rowDataF (that I pass in `<AgGridReact rowData={rowDataF}/>` ) and the data displayed visually in the Grid there is no common points. When I try to display the rowDataF in my function onClickRemove() I get an empty Array [].

I am a new in React/Ag-Grid-React and I need a help .

Even in the official site of Ag-Grid https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-transactions/#example-updating-with-transaction, in their example, I have tried to print the rowData after a row was deleted and the data passed in `<AgGridReact rowData={rowData}/>` itself didn't get updated although the applyTransaction worked only visually.
I would be very thankfull to you for any possible solutions or directions.